# Enable video calling with Linphone iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, linphone

I'm trying to enable video calling on my swift app using Linphone.
I was able to enable audio calling, but I can't make it working with video. The app is always crashing if I enable this line:

```
linphone_call_params_enable_video(linCallParams, 1)
```

I want to only receive video and audio here.

```
@objc func startVideoCall() {

    linphone_core_enable_video_display(theLinphone.lc, 1)
    linphone_core_enable_video_capture(theLinphone.lc, 1)

    let linCallParams = linphone_core_create_call_params(theLinphone.lc, nil)
    linphone_call_params_enable_video(linCallParams, 1)

    linphone_call_params_set_video_direction(linCallParams, LinphoneMediaDirectionSendRecv)
    linphone_call_params_set_audio_direction(linCallParams, LinphoneMediaDirectionSendRecv)

    let call = linphone_core_invite_with_params(theLinphone.lc, calleeAccount, linCallParams)

    linphone_core_set_native_video_window_id(theLinphone.lc, &videoStreamView)
    linphone_core_set_native_preview_window_id(theLinphone.lc, &videoStreamPreview)

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("Audio error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    linphone_call_params_unref(linCallParams)     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code combo fixed my issue

```
private func bridge<T: AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeRawPointer {
    let pointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque()
    return UnsafeRawPointer(pointer)
}

let viewPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: bridge(obj: view))
linphone_core_set_native_video_window_id(theLinphone.lc, viewPointer)
let previewPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: bridge(obj: previewStream))
linphone_core_set_native_preview_window_id(theLinphone.lc, previewPointer)
```

Comment: Can u please add some more details about, how to use this code for more clarification?